# Page Loads Earlier Than the Get Request (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in ReactJS. Now trying to make the GET request from an API using axios with the following code. But page loads earlier than the request so my state gives an empty array. I tried to solve it by using async and await but I couldn't succeed it since I don't know the React well, I guess. Please help, thank you a lot.

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function NewsPage(){

    const [news, setNews] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {    

    var axios = require("axios").default;

    var options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://api.newscatcherapi.com/v2/search',
      params: {q: 'obama', lang: 'en', sort_by: 'relevancy', page: '1'},
      headers: {
        'x-api-key': '**************'
      }
    };

    axios.request(options)
    .then(function (response) {console.log(response.data.articles)})
    .then(response => setNews(response.data.articles))
    .catch(function (error) {console.error(error)})

},[]);

    return (
        <div>
            Hello
            {news.map((eachnews) => {
                return <div key={eachnews.title}>
                    <h2>{eachnews.author}</h2>
                </div>
            })}
        </div>

    )
}

export default NewsPage
```

Answer (score 0):

This is **normal behavior** of React. Older frameworks block the whole page while loading, but React **renders** the page already **while loading**.

It is a design decision that makes perfectly sense. You can add a **loading animation** or a **skeleton** during loading. This is considered better practice instead of leaving the whole page white. Especially because you can then do **good error handling** that doesn't interrupt the UI.